# Getting errors when I run "python manage.py check"

Tags: python, django, anaconda, django-1.8

Ever since I have started my job I have not been able to run my web app locally. I have been going at this for a while I still cannot get a clean `python manage.py runserver` or `python manage.py check`.

I did once install Anaconda on here, is that affecting my paths?

Here is the error that I am getting.

```
(venv) BattleStationOnline 10:13:51 aggrigator$~python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/andynguyen/Desktop/aggrigator/aggrigator/accounts/models.py", line 21, in <module>
    from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simple_history/models.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.urls import reverse
ImportError: No module named urls
```

edit: I am running Django 1.8 and my webapp runs okay on my ubuntu server.

Comment: Did you name something in your project folder `django` or `django.*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Django:1.8 doc for reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/)

Use,

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

---

#### Additional Info

> **`django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`**
> Deprecated since version 1.10:
> In older versions, these functions are located in django.core.urlresolvers. Importing from the old location will continue to work until Django 2.0.